# How to cut specific part of string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I tried to get value of image src with click event by using this:

```
<img onclick='swap(this); return false;' style='width:auto;max-width:65px;max-height:55px' src="/member/sthumb/$image_path_array[$i]">
```

So when i click it, i get this value `/member/sthumb/$image_path_array[$i]`

Here is my javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function swap(image) {
      ...some code to cut the sthumb/ part from the string
      document.getElementById("main").src = image.src;
   }
</script>
```

In this javascript code, i would like to cut this specific part `sthumb/` out so the image.src will now be: `/member/$image_path_array[$i]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [String.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```
function swap(image) {
    //...some code to cut the sthumb/ part from the string
    document.getElementById("main").src = image.src.replace('/sthumb', '');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use simple replace method of String or it can be done using substring also
Solution1(Simple and Best):
function swap(image) {
    document.getElementById("main").src = image.src.replace('/sthumb', '');
}

Solution2:
function swap(image) {
var str=image.src;
var StringToCut='/sthumb';
document.getElementById("main").src = str.substring(0,str.indexOf(StringToCut))+str.substring(str.indexOf(StringToCut)+StringToCut.length);
}
```